# ¿Puede alguien ayudarme a analizar sintacticamente esta oración, y explicarme rapidamente?

Tags: preguntas

Necesito aprender como hacer un analisis sintactico de una oración, se hacerlo para frases cortas y sencillas, pero esta, está muy complicada para mi, podrian ayudarme por favor?

> No creo que exista ningún adolescente que no se sienta un guerrero desnudo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes en analizarla?  No podemos ayudarte tanto si no nos dices por qué no lo sabes hacer.

Answer (score 1):

> No creo que exista ningún adolescente que no se sienta un guerrero desnudo.

---

> No = **adverbio**
>
> Creo = **nucleo del predicado**
>
> que exista ningún adolescente = **una clausula subornidada sustantiva**
>
> exista (verbo), ningún (adverbio), adolescente (sujeto subordinado)
>
> que no se sienta un guerrero desnudo = **una clausula subordinada adjectival**